# IOS WebView App - Different View on different scree sizes

Tags: ios, uiwebview, scale

I'm absolute beginner in iOS-programming.
Now I'm trying to make a simple WebvView app. 
And I did it, but when I'm testing it on different screen sizes - it looks different.
Bottom line looks hidden on 3.5' device.
Here is some button that controls this action, but is there any way to make it scalable by device height automaticly, without that button?
Or it should to be a 2 different apps for different sizes?
Thanks!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternatively you can use *Auto Layout*. set top, left, right, and bottom constraints of your webview with 0 value. your web view size will always same as your device size.

[image]

Comment: Sure! It was so fast reply that system told me to wait a little bit, before I can do this :)